# Select different network interface for Zend_Service_Amazon_S3

Tags: php, zend-framework, network-interface

I wondered if it's possible to set the network interface (i.e. `eth0:1` or `eth0:2`) for the `Zend_Http_Client`, which is used in `Zend_Service_Amazon_S3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use socket bindto and enter the IP of your eth0:2

See Example #2 on this page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html